# JAXB with nested elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2-basics

```
<productInfo>
  <product>
    <productPrice>
      <price></price>
    </productPrice>
  </product>
<productInfo>
```

To create an XML like the above I am creating classes for `productInfo`, `product`, `productPrice` and then I am "unmarshalling" using JAXB annotations.

Is there any way to unmarshall without creating `product` class?

Comment: You can use @XmlTransient on Product if you do not want to marschall or unmarschall it. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html

Comment: I don't want to create a Product class , but i have to create a product element.

Comment: So you want to serialize a ProductInfo object without a Product field to a xml file that has a <product> tag and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use the `@XmlPath` extension in the MOXy implementation of JAXB to map this use case.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProductInfo {

    @XmlPath("product/productPrice/price/text()")
    private double price;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html